# Count rows with a where condition in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to count the number of rows in a table where a condition is true.

My query is:

```
SELECT
COUNT(SeqID0101),
COUNT(SeqID0102),
COUNT(SeqID0103),
COUNT(SeqID0104),
COUNT(SeqID0105),
COUNT(SeqID0106),
COUNT(SeqID0107),
COUNT(SeqID0108),
COUNT(SeqID0109),
COUNT(SeqID0110)
FROM
PH001_Hist
WHERE
SeqID0101 = 1 OR SeqID0102 = 1 OR OR SeqID0103 = 1 OR SeqID0104 = 1 OR SeqID0105 = 1 
OR SeqID0106 = 1 OR SeqID0107 = 1 OR SeqID0108 = 1 OR SeqID0109 = 1 OR SeqID0110 = 1
```

I keep reading other posts but can't find an answer to this issue.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and the desired outcome for that data? I, for one, was unable to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query that you have does not look correct and you can not count this way. However you can do something as

```
select
sum(SeqID0101 = 1) as SeqID0101,
sum(SeqID0102 = 1) as SeqID0102,
sum(SeqID0103 = 1) as SeqID0103,
sum(SeqID0104 = 1) as SeqID0104,
sum(SeqID0105 = 1) as SeqID0105,
sum(SeqID0106 = 1) as SeqID0106,
sum(SeqID0107 = 1) as SeqID0107,
sum(SeqID0108 = 1) as SeqID0108,
sum(SeqID0109 = 1) as SeqID0109,
sum(SeqID0110 = 1) as SeqID0110
from 
PH001_Hist
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select
sum(SeqID0101) as SeqID0101,
sum(SeqID0102) as SeqID0102,
sum(SeqID0103) as SeqID0103,
sum(SeqID0104) as SeqID0104,
sum(SeqID0105) as SeqID0105,
sum(SeqID0106) as SeqID0106,
sum(SeqID0107) as SeqID0107,
sum(SeqID0108) as SeqID0108,
sum(SeqID0109) as SeqID0109,
sum(SeqID0110) as SeqID0110
from 
PH001_Hist
```

Comment: Code-only answers are low-value on StackOverflow.